# Target Practice game in Pygame stops working after target has been shot a few times, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a Target Practice game in Pygame that speeds up every time the target is shot. After the target has been shot a few times the bullet and target collisions stop being registered. Below are the functions that I believe are relevant, can anyone see anything wrong?

Function for Target being missed:

```
def target_missed(stats, bullets):
"""Respond to target being missed."""

if stats.misses > 0:
    stats.misses -= 1


    # Empty list of bullets
    bullets.empty()

    # Pause.
    sleep(0.5)

else:
    stats.game_active = False
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
```

Function for Bullet-Target collisions:

```
def check_bullet_target_collisions(ai_settings, screen, ship, targets, bullets):
"""Respond to bullet-target collisions."""
# Remove any bullets and targets that have collided.
collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, targets, True, True)

if collisions:
    # Destroy existing bullets, speed up game, and create new target.
    bullets.empty()
    ai_settings.increase_speed()
    create_target(ai_settings, screen, targets)
```

Comment: Your `collisions`  test will *always* be True, since `pygame.sprite.groupcollide()` will put everything from group1 (bullets) into the resulting dictionary along with which members of group2 (targets) they collide with.  So I don't think your collisions ever worked properly.  Perhaps you need to re-work this piece of code.

Comment: I'll look into this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going wrong!

Basically, when the bullets move too quickly the collision isn't registered. So keep the bullet speed constant.

Settings.py

```
class Settings():
"""A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""

def __init__(self):
    """Initialise the game's settings."""
    self.screen_width = 1200    # Screen settings
    self.screen_height = 800
    self.bg_colour = (230, 230, 230)


     # Bullet settings
    self.bullet_width = 15      # Make the width bigger than height for sideways bullet
    self.bullet_height = 3
    self.bullet_colour = 60, 60, 60
    self.bullets_allowed = 3


    self.missed_attempts = 3         # Missed attempts allowed

    self.speedup_scale = 1.1          # How quickly the game speeds up

    self.initialize_dynamic_settings()


def initialize_dynamic_settings(self):
    """Initialize settings that change throughout the game."""
    self.ship_speed_factor = 5
    self.bullet_speed_factor = 100


    self.target_speed_factor = 5  # Target settings
    # fleet_direction of 1 represents right; -1 represents left.
    self.target_direction = 1


def increase_speed(self):
    """Increase speed settings."""
    self.ship_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
    self.bullet_speed_factor *= 1     # Keep bullet speed constant
    self.target_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
```

I was making the ship, bullet and target move faster at first, so that's where the problem lied. I hope everyone finds this helpful!